# Can JConsole show an MXBean attribute with type UUID as a String?

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

I have an MXBean that returns an attribute containing `Set<UUID>`.

When JConsole shows a UUID it treats it as composite data with two attributes - `leastSignificantBits` and `mostSignifitcantBits`.

Instead of changing my MXBean to return `Set<String>` is there some method (involving the server-side only) that would override the defaults and show the UUID in JConsole as if `toString()` had been called?

Answer (score 0):

Your resource class on the server side needs to implement

`javax.management.DynamicMBean` and override the method `public MBeanInfo getMBeanInfo()`. Here you need to return an appropriate object of `MBeanInfo`.

Specifically, you would need to convert the UUID to String in the `getAttributes()` method of returned `MBeanInfo` object.